# ajaxplorer:login from mysql table

Tags: mysql, file-management, pydio

Hi i am using ajaxplorer, here i want to use mysql database table to login to ajaxplorer..
here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`Guid` char(38) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`UserName` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Organization` char(38) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`rsguid` char(38) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`temppassword` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`SessionExpires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`IsAdmin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Guid`)
)
```

here user name is "admin" and temppassword is "ajaxplorer" using these credentials from user table i want to login in ajaxplorer..

please help me out

Comment: you need to (a) specify which language you are using (b) what is the code you have tried so far

Comment: Hi, satya have u used ajaxplorer before?

Comment: have tried it a few months back

Comment: btw  have you tried checking this link http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/administration/4-step-install/?PHPSESSID=01c7fb1605e1321f0bcc8351fe38c9ce

Comment: satya, i instaled it and working fine..but i want to use my own database in this..but i dont know hot to integrate it..could u please help me

Comment: check this link http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/developer-documentation/chapter-external-bridge/

Comment: satya, my point is i have mysql database i want to connect it from ajaxplorer.

Comment: ur link says that authentication with another application..i am not going to use any application just want to connect to MySQL database from ajaxplorer..

Answer (score 0):

1: Replace the auth driver and conf driver in bootstrap_plugins.php with the following:

```
    "CONF_DRIVER" => array(
        "NAME"      => "sql",
        "OPTIONS"   => array(
            "SQL_DRIVER"    => array(
                "driver"    => "mysql",
                "host"      => "db_server",
                "database"  => "db_name",
                "user"      => "db_username",
                "password"  => "db_password",
            ),
            )
),    

"AUTH_DRIVER" => array(
            "NAME"          => "sql",
             "OPTIONS"       => array(
            "SLAVE_MODE"  => true,  
                "SQL_DRIVER"    => array(
                                        "driver"    => "mysql",
                                        "host"      => "db_server",
                                        "database"  => "db_name",
                                        "user"      => "db_username",
                                        "password"  => "db_password"
                                            ),

               "TRANSMIT_CLEAR_PASS"   => false  // Don't touch this. It's unsafe (and useless here) to transmit clear password.
                                        )
                ),
```

2: You can find all the queries regarding user table and column names in pligins/auth.sql/class.sqlAuthDriver.php where you can customize them according to your requirement like renaming "ajaxp_user" to "user" etc.